# What Epictetus meant in "Enchiridon" XLVI?

Tags: ancient-philosophy

In Enchiridon ch. XLVI Epictetus wrote:

> If any conversation should arise among uninstructed persons about any theorem, generally be silent [...] And when a man shall say to you, that you know nothing, and you are not vexed, then be sure that you have begun the work (of Philosophy).

What does he meen by beginning the work of philosophy?

Answer (score 4):

Full [quote](http://classics.mit.edu/Epictetus/epicench.html) :

> **46**. Never call yourself a philosopher, nor talk a great deal among the unlearned about theorems, but act conformably to them. Thus, at an entertainment, don't talk how persons ought to eat, but eat as you ought. For remember that in this manner Socrates also universally avoided all ostentation. And when persons came to him and desired to be recommended by him to philosophers, he took and recommended them, so well did he bear being overlooked. So that if ever any talk should happen among the unlearned concerning philosophic theorems, be you, for the most part, silent. For there is great danger in immediately throwing out what you have not digested. And, if anyone tells you that you know nothing, and you are not nettled at it, then you may be sure that you have begun your business. For sheep don't throw up the grass to show the shepherds how much they have eaten; but, inwardly digesting their food, they outwardly produce wool and milk. Thus, therefore, do you likewise not show theorems to the unlearned, but the actions produced by them after they have been digested.

It includes some of [Epictetus](http://www.iep.utm.edu/epictetu/) precepts :

- do not "dogmatize", and teach your precepts with your acts (more than by words)
- follow the [Socratic path to knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates#Knowledge) :

> The statement "I know that I know nothing" is often attributed to Socrates, based on a statement in Plato's *Apology*. The conventional interpretation of this is that Socrates' wisdom was limited to an awareness of his own ignorance. Socrates considered virtuousness to require or consist of *phronēsis*, "thought, sense, judgement, practical wisdom, [and] prudence.